# What Makes These Two Array Adds Different?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this to take user input and was cleaning up code. I tried to fix this up and then the code stopped working.

This works:

```
    $BindVar[] = array();
    $BindVar[] = $Email;
    $BindVar[] = $pass;
```

This however does not:

```
    $BindVar[] = array($Email,$pass);
```

Here is the code that breaks when I change that line:

```
foreach ($BindVars as $value) {
        $input[] = "'" . $mysqli->real_escape_string($value) . "'"; // cleaning the input
    }
```

It gives this error:

> Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in

Comment: To see the result of what you've done, debug with `print_r($BindVar)` in each case... The difference between assigning and appending will become clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To understand your error message, I think it needs some explaination about Arrays.**

If you use brackets like `$bindVars[]`, you don't need to say, that it's an array by calling the `array()` function.

PHP understands the brackets `[]` as array declaration.

---

Your declarations with brackets `[]` **and** the `array()` function

```
$BindVars[] = array($Email,$pass); 

// same as:
$BindVars = array(
    array($Email, $pass);
);
```

**creates a new Array *inside* `$bindVars`  containing the elements `$Email` & `$pass`.**

So, `$bindVars` is already an Array because of the brackets `[]`. That gives us a **Multi-dimensional Array**.

In your code, it's a **2-Dimensional Array, which represents a table**. It's the most frequently used Multi-Dimensional Array.

A *3-Dimensional Array* like `$bindVars[][][]` (3 pairs of brackets) represents a cube or a die.

A *4-Dimenisional Array* `$bindVars[][][][]` (4 pairs of brackets) is then a cube with another dimension on each side of it. *--- With every further Dimension it gets more mind-boggling ---*

Back to the **2-Dimensional Array**:

The **1. Dimension** is the row or record

The **2. Dimension** is the column or field.

```
// 1. Dimension: 1. row
echo $bindVars[0]; // Output: Array() Here is your mysqli error coming from!
```

> Warning: mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be
>   string, array given ...

```
/* --- 1. Record/Row --- */
// 2. Dimension: 1. row, 1. column
echo $bindVars[0][0]; // Output: value of $Email
// 2. Dimension: 1. row, 2. column
echo $bindVars[0][1]; // Output: value of $pass

 /* --- 2. Record/Row --- */
// 1. column
echo $bindVars[1][0]; // Output: value of $Email
// 2. column
echo $bindVars[1][1]; // Output: value of $pass

// And so on
```

Change

```
$BindVar[] = array($Email,$pass);
```

to

```
$BindVar = array($Email,$pass);
```

Comment: That actually doesn't answer what's the difference between those two arrays

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky well He did show me how to make it work. several others explain the array and the value of the pointer vs the the contents of the object. that is why I gave the answer to him.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that

Answer (score 2):

```
$BindVar[] = $Email;
$BindVar[] = $pass;
```

That's an array with **2** String elements.

```
$BindVar[] = array($Email,$pass);
```

That's an array with **1** array element containing **2** string elements

Both are different, and should be dealt with differently. First one is a simple array and the second one is a multi-dimensional array.

And oh, I forgot about your

```
$BindVar[] = array();
```

That will result in unexpected behavior, That actually adds a blank array element to your `$BindVar` array. From the looks of it I think you just wish to declare that $BindVar as an array, do this

```
$BindVar = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

`[]` are for appending a new item to the array. `$BindVar[] = array(...)` is putting another array in that item of the first array.  That's why running `real_escape_string` on that item fails, because that item is not a string but a nested array.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo notation of how your code structures the array:

First:

```
$BindVar[] = array();
$BindVar[] = $Email;
$BindVar[] = $pass;

$BindVar
(
    Array(),
    Email,
    Pass
)
```

Second:

```
$BindVar[] = array($Email,$pass);

$BindVar
(
    Array(Email, Pass)
)
```

Those two are clearly different.

Answer (score 1):

```
$BindVar[] = array();
^^^^^^^^^^---- push a new array into $BindVar
```

If `$bindvar` was undefined before this, you'll be creating a new array, and then pushing an empty array into it. That makes `$BindVar[0]` be an array, and when you loop over it for your binding operation, you'll be passing that new empty array to the bind call. hence your error.

You probably want just:

```
$BindVar = array();
        ^--- no []
```

Answer (score 0):

### U can change your like bellow

`$BindVar[] = array($Email,$pass);` to `$BindVar = array($Email,$pass);`