# Assigning variable names to arrays not working

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, literals

I am trying to output array content in a for loop. When I use the literal name of the array, it works. When I try to use a variable assigned to that name it fails. I need to use a variable to allow the page to  display the correct content based on user's choice.

the array, saved as an include, is 2-dimensional of the form:

```
$newsArray2012 = array(
    array(string_a, string_b, stringc),
    array(string_a, string_b, stringc),
    array(string_a, string_b, stringc), etc.,
    );
```

The for loop looks like this:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
    echo "<p class='portrait'><a name='".$newsArray2012[$row][1]."'></a>\n
    <em>".$newsArray2012[$row][0]."</em></p>\n
    <img src='/Pictures/".$newsArray2012[$row][1]."' width='72' height='80' alt='' />\n";
    echo $newsArray2012[$row][2]."\n";
    }
```

That works.

I've assigned $newsCurrent = newsArray2012. When I substitute $newsCurrent for $newsArray2012 in the for loop, I do not get any output. In testing, I found that print_r($$newsCurrent) will dump the full array and even though that's goofy, I tried the $$ version in the for loop but it does not work there.

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: see my answer about 2-dimenisonal arrays http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548019/what-makes-these-two-array-adds-different/23548066#23548066

Comment: #pc-shooter - that helps clarify some options for declaring an array but I'm not sure where my coding fails. If I add brackets, i.e., `$newsCurrent = newsArray2012()` I can't even get a print_r dump.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since $$newsCurrent worked with print_r, but not in the for loop, I assumed that PHP had a problem with the $$. Since it allowed the $$ in print_r, I made the leap that it would accept a re-assignment as follows:

```
$pageBios = $$newsCurrent;
```

This actually worked. I placed $pageBios in the for loop and had success. I'm not happy with it because the $$ format is not right - at least I've never seen it. So while I need to move forward due to deadlines, I would really like to clean this up - so please feel free to show me a non-moronic approach. Thanks.